# How do I set up RESTful attribute routing in ASP.Net Core API if using Namespace version routing

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, attributerouting

I am building an ASP.Net Core 1.1.0 web API.

As a supporting comment, I have chosen to use Peter Lazzarino's  versionrouting NuGet package to allow me to separate my controllers into different namespaces (and folders) based on version. I configured this in my Startup.cs as recommended by Peter and it builds without errors. I am using

```
var apiPrefix = "api";
```

in Startup.cs to allow all of my routes to start with api, as per Peter's recommendation.

I want to follow RESTful guidelines and utilize HTTP verb attributes for my methods.

I want my clients to be able to go to http://companyname.com/api/v1/mycontroller/status and since I have MyController located in the the folder "Controllers\v1\MyController.cs" in my API project, the versionrouting library should be able to find it.

Within my controller, I have the following;

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers.v1
{
    public class MyController : Controller
    {

        // GET: ~/api/v1/mycontroller/status
        [HttpGet("/status")]
        public JsonResult Status()
        {
            return Json(new { status = "API is running" });
        }

    }
}
```

However, navigating to http://companyname.com/api/v1/mycontroller/status gives me a 404 error.

I had tried to leave this question as a comment in the SO post [How can versioning be done in ASP.NET Core Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304961/how-can-versioning-be-done-in-asp-net-core-web-api/38305277)
, but I do not have a high enough reputation yet in StackOverflow to leave a comment. :(

So, hopefully someone here can help me out.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: If you change the attribute on your action to just `[HttpGet]`, does it behave any differently? Can you post your Startup.cs as well? Also, what do the logs show when a request comes in?

Comment: You should install and utilize Swashbuckle so you can actually see what end points are produced by your application.

Comment: @Nate Barbettini - Just changing the action attribute to [HttpGet] did not work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Routes Attributes on the controller as specified in [the asp.net core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api) that way you can have versioning of your api but then you will have to add it to every controller to keep your code in sync, i do not know exactly where you can add it globally. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can simply decorate your controller with:

```
[Route("api/v1/[controller]/[action]")]
public class MyController : Controller
{

    // GET: ~/api/v1/mycontroller/status
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Status()
    {
        return Json(new { status = "API is running" });
    }

}
```

Then your route will be:

```
http://companyname.com/api/v1/mycontroller/status
```

Comment: Adding the Route attribute to the class did not fix the issue. I am still getting a 404. 

Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://companyname.com/api/v1/mycontroller/status  
Request finished in 5.9769ms 404

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem required that I do not use any Route attribute for the class (since the namespaceversioning NuGet code is building essentially a MapRoute for api/v1/mycontroller) and also not to use the forward slash in front of the HttpGet action attribute property (i.e. [HttpGet("Status")] instead of [HttpGet("/Status")] ). Once I made that change, it started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This particular feature wasn't supported at the time, [API Versioning](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning) now supports achieving this particular setup out-of-the-box using [API Version Conventions](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Version-Conventions).

You need only configure your application and apply the route constraint in your templates.

```cs
services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
    options.Conventions.Add( new VersionByNamespaceConvention() );
```

Your service now only need be defined as:

```cs
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]/[action]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: ~/api/v1/my/status
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Status()
    {
        return Ok(new { status = "API is running" });
    }
}
```